# Use fmt::Write or io::Write trait for my writable type?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that can be converted to text through a complex series of method calls which contain numerous `write!` calls. This text can be written to a file or to a debug log. I am trying to decide whether to use [`fmt::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Write.html) or [`io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html). I can't really use both because then all of the writing methods would need to be duplicated.

Simplified example:

```rust
impl MyType {
    fn write_it(&self, writer: &mut impl ???) {
//                                       ^ fmt::Write or io::Write?
        self.write_header(writer);
        self.write_contents(writer);
        self.write_footer(writer);
    }

    fn write_header(&self, writer: &mut impl ???) {
        write!(writer, "...")
    }
    // and more...
}
```

The docs for `fmt::Write` say,

> ...This is similar to the standard library's io::Write trait, but it is only intended for use in libcore.

So this leads me to believe I should use `io::Write`. This (obviously) will work well for I/O types like `BufWriter`. And it seems notable that [serde_json does it this way](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.to_writer.html).

```rust
// if I use io::Write, I can do this
my_type.write_it(&mut BufWriter::new(File::create("my-file.txt")?)?;
```

I also want to use my type with `format!` and similar macros. So I need to implement `Display`. In fact, isn't `Display` the de-facto trait for a type that can be represented as a `String`?

```rust
// I want to do this
println!("Contents:\n{}", my_type);

// or this
let mut s = String::new();
write!(s, "{}", my_type);
```

So I think I'll just tie in my implementation with `Display`. But here's the problem:

```rust
impl Display for MyType {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        self.write_it(f)?;
//                    ^ the trait `std::io::Write` is not implemented for `std::fmt::Formatter<'_>`
    }
}
```

I can fix this by using `impl fmt::Write`, but then I lose the I/O capability mentioned before. There is no adapter between the two types (I assume there would be one if that were an intended usage). So I am caught between the two. Which trait should I use? Is there an idiomatic way to get the functionality of both?

**Edit: Adapter?**

@ÖmerErden suggested creating an adapter like the following. I'm just not sure what conditions will cause the UTF-8 conversion to fail. Is that conversion guaranteed to not fail as long as I write valid UTF-8 with `write!`? It seems too risky to me.

```rust
struct Adapter<'a> {
    f: &'a mut dyn fmt::Write,
}

impl<'a> io::Write for Adapter<'a> {
    fn write(&mut self, b: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, io::Error> {
        let s = str::from_utf8(b)
            .map_err(|_| io::Error::from(io::ErrorKind::Other))?;
        self.f.write_str(s)
            .map_err(|_| io::Error::from(io::ErrorKind::Other))?;
        Ok(b.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you pass the writers into your concrete type? IMHO if your type is going to be a writer then it should implement the each `Writer`s according to need, then to not duplicate your i/o logic your type might have private functions which produce header, contents and footer. Then these producers can be   used by implementation of any `Writer`

Comment: @ÖmerErden That would involve creating a lot of `String`s unnecessarily.

Comment: You already create those Strings while using `write!` macro inside `write_x` functions?

Comment: No, `write!` writes directly to the target without creating a `String`

Comment: I didn't say `write!` creates extra `String`, you create `String` before using `write!`. According to your response you care about streaming your data,  instead of bulk serialize you want to sink immediately when part of your object is ready. Using `io:Write` makes sense on this but for `Display` you'll need a bulk serialization, it is not made for streaming. To do that you may implement your `Display` like this instead of sending the formatter: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0175ef83ac2a0f052b57cf747e5a43a

Comment: Display _does_ support streaming because the method accepts a `fmt::Formatter` which implements `fmt::Write`. Your solution puts the entire contents in a `Vec` before passing it to `Formatter` which indeed works but is not optimal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217613/discussion-between-cambunctious-and-omer-erden).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct thing to do is implement `Display` for your type, and not have a `write_it` method at all. Ideally, your `header`, `content`, and `footer` also implement `Display`, because then you can write something like this:

```rust
impl Display for MyType {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}{}{}", self.header, self.content, self.footer)
    }    
}
```

However, if that's not possible, you can still write out your implementation manually like you did in your sample code.

> In fact, isn't Display the de-facto trait for a type that can be represented as a String?

It's more accurate to say that `Display` is the de-facto trait for a type that can be written to something. Converting things to strings is just one of the many use cases for `Display`, but on its own it doesn't create any intermediary strings.

Comment: The parts "header, content, footer" were to create a simplified example. The actual type has numerous parts. Splitting it into multiple parts that implement Display only adds complexity.

Comment: Sure. In that case, I'd recommand putting your logic in `Display::fmt`, refactoring as necessary into private helper methods that take an `&mut fmt::Formatter`

Comment: `fmt::Formatter` is also `impl fmt::Write`. This seems to be the answer, even though it sort of feels wrong to me to not use `io::Write`. But I discovered that std provides an [adapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#1486-1489) between the two traits under the hood. So `Display` + `write!` will fit the bill.

Comment: I'd elaborate a bit. If your goal is to write private helper methods to assist with an implementation of `Display::fmt`, then those methods should just take an `&mut fmt::Formatter`, rather than a generic `fmt::Write`, because you'll never be calling them in any other context. But yes, once you have a `Display` implementation, you can `write!` it to anything with a `write_fmt` method, which includes both `io::Write` and `fmt::Write`.

Comment: I prefer `&mut impl Write` but that's just my taste.

Comment: Can I ask why, if these methods aren't exported? It's worth remembering that `Display::fmt` has fairly specific interface requirements- you're only allowed to return errors specifically that the Formatter returns; you can't return your own errors. This requirement may not be well represented in your interface if you take an `impl Write`.

Comment: The `Write` trait better describes the requirements of the methods because I specifically only need to use `write!`. The error type is determined by `Write::write_fmt` either way so I don't think that is a factor. Also, I could more easily change my design to accept `impl io::Write` instead.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation to the OP, but don't want to impl Display because there are multiple textual representations of my type.  Some representations are large, so I don't want them to be what shows up by default every time somebody prints an object.  In addition to Display, I _also_ would like separate methods that render the type to either a writer or a String; but String isn't io::Write, so how do I avoid duplication?  In other languages, I'd adapt a streaming version to an in-memory version using a stringstream or StringWriter.  String _is_ fmt::Write.

Comment: String is `fmt::Write`, which is why generally the recommendation is to `impl Display` and then use `write!`, which (via `write_fmt`) supports both `fmt::Write` and `io::Write`. Often you can handle multiple textual representations by extracting parameters from the `Formatter` passed to `Display`. For instance, `Debug` uses `"{!#?}"` instead of `{!?}` to handle pretty printing; the `#` is accessible via the `Formatter::alternate()` method.